# Push a view controller from a Pod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have a CocoaPod Framework in my project and I need to modify it to push a certain view controller. But I'm getting below error.

[image: error]

And I need to access global functions and variables in my Project from here too. Thanks in advance.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn’t generally modify pods

Comment: This is not working because the pod cannot access your project’s code

Comment: You should try subclassing or write extension for pod classes, to which you wanted to provide your specific functionality.

Answer (score 1):

**Error 1:**

Don't modify pod directly. If you want to modify your pod, that subclass the pod class or create an extension of that class. If you modify directly, after pod update your change won't be found.

**Error 2:**

```
Use of undeclared type 'MyViewController'
```

this means that `MyViewController` isn't in your module. You can't access to other module's class directly. To import a class from different module, you have to import the module.

Suppose, `MyViewController` is present in Module `ViewControllerModule` , just write

`import ViewControllerModule`

you will get access of `MyViewController` now.

Answer (score 0):

The cocoa pod are not generally modified in project. You need to use as it.

If you modify a pod and later time if there is any update in pod and you update you pod then your changes flush away(or you may get an error in pod update)

And the error itself says

> Use of undeclared type 'MyViewController'

It means that you need to `MyViewController` is not available in your project.

If it is available in cocoa pod then you need to import that pod and then you can use that.

After importing you can use that class for subclassing or create an extension for that existing class.

Answer (score 0):

**You can get ViewController from Pods using below three step**

1. **Get Bundle Indetifire from Pods Target and find bundle**

   ```
   let frameworkBundle = Bundle(identifier:"Pods Bundle identifire")
   ```
2. **Get Storyboard from pods using storyboardName**

   ```
   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Pods StoryBoard ID", bundle: frameworkBundle)
   ```
3. **Get ViewController from Storyboard using ViewController Identifier**

   ```
   let YourController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "View Controller Identifire")
   ```